# how to move WordPress theme with pages and Elementor design

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I have this design and pages on
 https://www.giscorponline.com/
and I want to copy it to https://clebshop.com/

But when I take back up from the site A to restore it on the site B and get the pages with the design it does the job but it breaks plugin linked to a CRM

So, I wanna carefully backup just the theme, pages, recent post, menu, and media library is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can backup the theme by "copy and paste", for entities like pages and posts have a look at the https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/. What is actually the issue with the CRM link? Maybe it's easier to fix that.

Comment: Let us know how you are taking backup. with plugins or folder?